# Read array string of variable length in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I wanted to read an array having different lengths for the columns in the array. For example please refer to the list below.

```
binary,none1,Param,none2

77,2601,54,55

70,,25,224

71,,33,38

67,,22,40

0,,14,

0,,47,

0,,21,

0,,88,

0,,50,

0,,17,

0,,11,

0,,26,
```

(Please replace the commas with space to get list)

I want to import this to python and insert "null" for empty set. I am trying to convert this into a symmetrical array. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try None instead of null..

Comment: insert `null` where?

Comment: consider the second row of numbers, 70,,25,224. If replace the comma then I get -->  70 empty empty 25 224. In the text file the "empty" is actually empty space and when I import this into python I wanted to replace it with null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, `None` is the Python equivalent of null. You could achieve this with the following approach:

```
# Keep column headers. Convert numbers to numbers. Empty strings into None (empty "set")

def get_col(col):
    if col:
        try:
            return int(col)
        except:
            return col
    else:
        return None


rows = [row.split (',') for row in data.split ('\n')]
# Convert empty columns into None and
rows = [[get_col(col) for col in cols] for cols in rows]
```

This would result in `rows` looking as follows:

```
[['binary', 'none1', 'Param', 'none2'], [77, 2601, 54, 55], [70, None, 25,  224], [71, None, 33, 38],   etc....
```

Replacing the get_col function as follows:

```
def get_col(col):
    if col:
        return col
    else:
        return 'null'
```

Would give you `rows` looking as follows:

```
[['binary', 'none1', 'Param', 'none2'], ['77', '2601', '54', '55'], ['70', 'null', '25', '224'], ['71', 'null', '33', '38'],   etc...
```

(Using Python 2.7.9)

Answer (score 0):

```
fileName = raw_input ()
try:
    file = open (fileName)
    input = file.read ()
    file.close ()
except: # Test case
    input = '''77 2601 54 55
    70  25 224
    71  33 38
    67  22 40
    0  14 
    0  47 
    0  21 
    0  88 
    0  50 
    0  17 
    0  11 
    0  26 '''

array = [
    [
        (element if element else None)
        for element in line.split (' ')
    ]
    for line in input.split ('\n')
]

for row in array:
    print row
```

Comment: Jac, if this was in a text file like I mentioned in the comment above, the commas are actually empty space, firstly I want to import it into python and then modify it such a way that I get a symmetrical array.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by symmetrialc array? Mirror symmetrical in the main diagonal?